# How can I change tab to spaces in Nodeclipse .njs file formatter

Tags: eclipse, node.js, editor, jsdt, nodeclipse

It's easy to set up Code Formatter Preferences for JS file editor but what about Nodeclipse Node.js file Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Nodeclipse 0.9 default Editor for .njs files is TextEditor-based. It has no advanced features, except for those in `Window -> Preferences -> Editors -> Text Editors`.

Right-click .njs file and select `Open with -> Nodeclipse JSDT-based Editor`.
Then you have all those features found in Preferences under JavaScript (including formatting).

Nodeclipse JSDT-based Editor will be back default for .njs files in Nodeclipse 0.10